# Как растянуть RecyclerView по всей высоте

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-scrollview

Нужно вложить RecyclerView в CardView, но в таком случаи список скроллится внутри CardView. Как заставить список скроллится вместе с cardview? Т.е. растянуть карту со списком на всю высоту контента.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: так не получится. единственное что можно сделать это в cardview layout_height сделать match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен тут `ScrollView` - просто уберите его, а для `CardView` поставьте высоту во весь экран - `match_parent`.

Вообще вложенные скролящиеся конейнеры - плохая практика. Они ещё кое-как работают в случае вертикальный+горизонтальный (с утечками памяти, кои надо руками чинить). Когда вы хотите так сделать вам надо остановиться и придумать как избежать этого всеми возможными способами